Combining multiple dummy variables into one categorical variable
I'm trying to combine multiple binary variables coded as 1 and 0, and sometimes NA if no data is reported, into one categorical variable/column for race. If multiple race values are recorded, I would like to the row code to be "multiracial" in the new race variable.
I tried to replicate prior solutions posted here but they didn't work for me.
structure(list(sex = c("Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"), zip_code = c(20695L, 
20854L, 20650L, 21401L, 20637L, 22101L), race_nhw = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), race_nhb = c("No", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No"), race_hlx = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No"), race_as = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), race_aian = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), race_nhpi = c("No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No"), health_ins = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes"), ins_priv = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes"), ins_medicare = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"
), ins_medicaid = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), ins_milit = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), ins_state = c("No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No"), ins_ihs = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No"), chvsc_chf = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chvsc_lvdsfxn = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chvsc_htn = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), chvsc_dm = c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes"), chvsc_stroke = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    chvsc_tia = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chvsc_vte = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chvsc_vascdz = c("No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), chvsc_mi = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "Yes"), chvsc_pad = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), chvsc_aortpl = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), cmb_cld = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No"), 
    cmb_cad = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No"), cmb_osa = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes"), hasbl_htn_un = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), hasbl_abnl_renalfxn = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), hasbl_abnl_livfxn = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), hasbl_bleed = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "Yes", "No"), hasbl_labileinr = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No"), hasbl_alc = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), hasbl_antipl = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
    "No"), hasbl_nsaid = c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No"
    ), af_symptom = c("Symptomatic", "Symptomatic", "Symptomatic", 
    "Symptomatic", "Symptomatic", "Symptomatic"), af_class = c("Persistent", 
    "Persistent", "Paroxysmal", "Paroxysmal", "Paroxysmal", "Paroxysmal"
    ), valv_af = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), hx_mvr = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), hx_mvrep = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    cardiomyop = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), cm_icm = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), cm_nicm = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "Yes", "No", "No"), cm_restr = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), cm_hypertr = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), cm_other = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    lvef_assessed = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), 
    lvef = c(NA, NA, NA, 25L, NA, 55L), wt = c(97.6, 100.2, 95.3, 
    95.6, 120, 115.4), ht = c(180, 177, 185, 158, 160, 190), 
    pulse = c(53L, 65L, 60L, 75L, 60L, 56L), sbp = c(98L, 128L, 
    120L, 118L, 117L, 108L), dbp = c(59L, 85L, 62L, 88L, 48L, 
    58L), inr = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), creat = c(0.6, 1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3), tbili = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ab_complex_fractionated = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), ab_cryo = c("Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), ab_convergent = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), ab_empiric_LA_linear = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), ab_focal = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), ab_ganglion_plexus = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), ab_pvi = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes"), ab_seg_pv = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    ab_rotor_based_mapping = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), ab_widearea_circumf = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), dc_rhythm_sinus = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


Hi Waseem, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you paste your data into the question rather than as an image? You could copy-paste the output of dput(head(df)) where df is your data.

Not sure if I did it right.

I updated my answer as per your request and modified your new example data to reflect your actual data. Does that work for you? If not, let me know and I will amend where necessary.

Based on the OP's update and edit request, answer updated. I modified your example data so that it replicates your actual data e.g. each person has a unique ID and so there is at least one person of mixed race.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- structure(list(sex = c("Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"), zip_code = c(20695L, 
20854L, 20650L, 21401L, 20637L, 22101L), race_nhw = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), race_nhb = c("Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No"), race_hlx = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No"), race_as = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), race_aian = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), race_nhpi = c("No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No"), health_ins = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes"), ins_priv = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes"), ins_medicare = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"
), ins_medicaid = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), ins_milit = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), ins_state = c("No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No"), ins_ihs = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No"), chvsc_chf = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chvsc_lvdsfxn = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chvsc_htn = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), chvsc_dm = c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes"), chvsc_stroke = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    chvsc_tia = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chvsc_vte = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), chvsc_vascdz = c("No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), chvsc_mi = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "Yes"), chvsc_pad = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), chvsc_aortpl = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), cmb_cld = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No"), 
    cmb_cad = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No"), cmb_osa = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes"), hasbl_htn_un = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), hasbl_abnl_renalfxn = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), hasbl_abnl_livfxn = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), hasbl_bleed = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "Yes", "No"), hasbl_labileinr = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No"), hasbl_alc = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), hasbl_antipl = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
    "No"), hasbl_nsaid = c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No"
    ), af_symptom = c("Symptomatic", "Symptomatic", "Symptomatic", 
    "Symptomatic", "Symptomatic", "Symptomatic"), af_class = c("Persistent", 
    "Persistent", "Paroxysmal", "Paroxysmal", "Paroxysmal", "Paroxysmal"
    ), valv_af = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), hx_mvr = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), hx_mvrep = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    cardiomyop = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), cm_icm = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), cm_nicm = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "Yes", "No", "No"), cm_restr = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), cm_hypertr = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), cm_other = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    lvef_assessed = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), 
    lvef = c(NA, NA, NA, 25L, NA, 55L), wt = c(97.6, 100.2, 95.3, 
    95.6, 120, 115.4), ht = c(180, 177, 185, 158, 160, 190), 
    pulse = c(53L, 65L, 60L, 75L, 60L, 56L), sbp = c(98L, 128L, 
    120L, 118L, 117L, 108L), dbp = c(59L, 85L, 62L, 88L, 48L, 
    58L), inr = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), creat = c(0.6, 1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3), tbili = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ab_complex_fractionated = c("No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), ab_cryo = c("Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), ab_convergent = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), ab_empiric_LA_linear = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No", "No"), ab_focal = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), ab_ganglion_plexus = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No"), ab_pvi = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes"), ab_seg_pv = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    ab_rotor_based_mapping = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), ab_widearea_circumf = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
    "No"), dc_rhythm_sinus = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df <- mutate(df, anon_id = 1:n()) |>
  relocate(anon_id)


df1 <- df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("race_"),
               names_to = "race",
               names_prefix = "race_",
               values_to = "value") |>
  filter(value == "Yes") |>
  group_by(anon_id) |>
  mutate(tmp = n(),
         race = if_else(tmp > 1, "multiracial", race)) |>
  distinct() |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-tmp)
    
df1[,c(1:5,ncol(df1)-1)]
# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#   anon_id sex    zip_code health_ins ins_priv race       
#     <int> <chr>     <int> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      
# 1       1 Male      20695 Yes        Yes      multiracial
# 2       2 Male      20854 Yes        Yes      nhw        
# 3       3 Male      20650 Yes        Yes      nhw        
# 4       4 Female    21401 Yes        No       nhb        
# 5       5 Female    20637 Yes        No       nhw        
# 6       6 Male      22101 Yes        Yes      nhw


Consider
> race_df
  id race_nhw race_nhb race_hlx race_as race_aian race_nhpi
1  1      Yes       No      Yes      No        No        No
2  2      Yes       No       No      No        No        No
3  3       No       No       No     Yes        No        No
4  4       No       No     <NA>      No       Yes        No
5  5       No       No      Yes     Yes        No        No
6  6       No       No       No     Yes        No        No

First, store names referring to race in a vector, since we need it multiple times.
> rc <- grep('race', names(race_df), value=TRUE)

Next, using max.col on <value_matrix> == 'Yes' we find column of (first) 'Yes' position which we use to subset stored rc names and replace them with 'multi', if rowSums of <value_matrix> == 'Yes' is > 1.
> transform(race_df,
+           race=replace(
+             gsub('.*_', '', rc)[
+               max.col(race_df[rc] == 'Yes')
+             ], 
+             rowSums(race_df[rc] == 'Yes') > 1L,
+             'multi'))
  id race_nhw race_nhb race_hlx race_as race_aian race_nhpi  race
1  1      Yes       No      Yes      No        No        No multi
2  2      Yes       No       No      No        No        No   nhw
3  3       No       No       No     Yes        No        No    as
4  4       No       No     <NA>      No       Yes        No  <NA>
5  5       No       No      Yes     Yes        No        No multi
6  6       No       No       No     Yes        No        No    as

This yields an NA if there are NA values in a row.
Handling missing values
If you are sure, that such an NA is the same as a 'No', you could replace NA with 0 and use na.rm in rowSums.
> max.col.na <- \(x) max.col(replace(x, is.na(x), 0L))
> rc <- grep('race', names(race_df), value=TRUE)
> transform(race_df,
+           race=replace(
+             gsub('.*_', '', rc)[
+               max.col.na(race_df[rc] == 'Yes')
+             ], 
+             rowSums(race_df[rc] == 'Yes', na.rm=TRUE) > 1L,
+             'multi'))
  id race_nhw race_nhb race_hlx race_as race_aian race_nhpi  race
1  1      Yes       No      Yes      No        No        No multi
2  2      Yes       No       No      No        No        No   nhw
3  3       No       No       No     Yes        No        No    as
4  4       No       No     <NA>      No       Yes        No  aian
5  5       No       No      Yes     Yes        No        No multi
6  6       No       No       No     Yes        No        No    as

However, using multiple imputation might be the better option.

Data:
> dput(race_df)
structure(list(id = 1:6, race_nhw = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "No"), race_nhb = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
    race_hlx = c("Yes", "No", "No", NA, "Yes", "No"), race_as = c("No", 
    "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), race_aian = c("No", "No", 
    "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), race_nhpi = c("No", "No", "No", 
    "No", "No", "No")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")


You can do the following:
race = c("nhw", "nhb", "hix", "as", "aian", "nhpi")

f <- \(yn) {
  r = race[which(yn=="Yes")]
  if_else(length(r)>1, "Multiracial",r)
}

library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(rowwise(df), race=f(c_across(starts_with("race"))))

